# How to format jbuilder value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I got a jbuilder response like below

```
{
  "name": "amb_devcernerpowerchart_com:patient_val2",
  "value": "{\"value\"=>\"patient_value\", \"expiration\"=>31536000, \"created_datetime\"=>\"2019-12-09T12:09:59Z\"}"
}
```

I want to only value part of value i.e i want output like below.

```
{
  "name": "amb_devcernerpowerchart_com:patient_val2",
  "value": "value"=>"patient_value"
}
```

How do i get this?

Jbuilder file looks like this

```
json.name @component.preference_data.id
json.value @component.preference_data.value
```

Comment: You'd have to provide more information about what your existing JBuilder looks like currently. Only then would it be possible to evaluate what is to be added/removed.

Comment: Yes, the response looks like this. But in order to identify what needs to be changed, we'd need to have a look at the JBuilder code.

Comment: This is what the JBuilder response looks like currently. I mean, this is the output that we receive when the JBuilder is executed. What about the input? There'd be a file which defines `json.name <some_name>` etc. That's the one we'd need to determine what to change

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal I have edited the question now with the jbuilder input.

Comment: the output you want is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it seems as though the data that you are receiving in the `value` field is a stringified JSON. You would have to parse the JSON and retrieve the required value as follows:

```
json.value JSON.parse(@component.preference_data.value)['value']
```

Basically, `@component.preference_data.value` returns a string, which is parsed into a JSON using `JSON.parse`. At the end of that, we get a hash whose `'value'` field is retrieved.